# How to store the timestamp as decimal(17,3) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, decimal

I try to generate a trigger, in the trigger statement I have to set a column of type decimal(17,3) with the actual timestamp or the seconds of unix timestamp, but could not find a solution.

Comment: May I ask you - why? Why do you need to store a 4-byte integer number in a decimal(17,3) field type?

Comment: An remote host send also timestamps which must be stored in this field, but the timestamps from the remote host comes with milliseconds. The MySql types date or timestamp are not able to store milliseconds, that's why I'm using decimal(17,3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

specify the datatype in the mysql table as decimal(17,3) hibernate map decimal to the Java type BigDecimal, and the with a simple function:

```
public static Date bigDec2Date(BigDecimal tsp) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(tsp.longValue());
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Java Code)

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());// current time
      String decimalTime=  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss.SSS").format(timestamp);
        System.err.println(decimalTime);
```

And in MySQL:

```
SELECT timestamp('<decimalTime>');// eg:-
```